# Participle clause in a sentence

Tags: participles

Is this a correct sentence? Is the participle clause correctly used?

"The monastery consists of several buildings each bearing different purpose."

Comment: If you add a comma after "buildings" and replace "bearing" with "having", it will sound just fine.

Comment: Thank you for responding

Comment: You are very welcome Tatyana :) (the indefinite article before "purpose" is also missing)

Comment: It does not sound right to me. I suggest "The monastery consists of several buildings, each for a different purpose."

Comment: "With", "for", "having" ..a different purpose - in the order of frequency, according to Ngram https://tinyurl.com/v9sspc9

Comment: @RejlanGivens my comment originally had "with" but I edited it to "for" because a building is inanimate.

Comment: I understand Weather Vane. I was looking to fit an ing verb into the existing structure. I don't  mind "each having a different purpose" or "each serving a different purpose", both sound fine to me. To answer Tatiana's initial question:  participial clauses are commonly used for this purpose. In your sentence the ing clause has a role similar to that of a comparable relative clause: ..which have different purposes.

Comment: Singular "purpose" doesn't sound right to me. It should be either "a different purpose" or "different purposes".